# Examples of functions that are 1-1 and onto

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Just starting with discrete maths.

Set $A = \{e,f,g\}$ and Set $B = \{2,5\}$

Q1. Give an example of a function $\space f: B \rightarrow A$ that is not 1-1.

I am not used to having the elements of the set given to me. I am thinking maybe something along the lines of:

$$f(2) = f(5) = e$$

Q2. Give an example of $\space g: P(B) \rightarrow A $ that is onto.

I don't know how to tackle this one.

Juan

Comment: Could you do it if we replaced $P(B)$ with another $4$-element set, e.g. $\lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4\rbrace$?

Comment: yes as I could say that $f(1) = e$, $f(2) = f$, $f(3) = g$ and $f(4) = g$

Comment: Good! Now do the same for $\lbrace \emptyset, \lbrace 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 5 \rbrace, \lbrace 2, 5 \rbrace \rbrace$. It's a $4$ element set like any other.

Comment: So can I say that $f(2,5) = e$, $f(2) = f$ and $f(3) = g$, can you enter the empty set into a function?

Comment: Well, $f(\lbrace 2, 5\rbrace)$ instead of $f(2, 5)$, $f(\lbrace 2 \rbrace)$ instead of $f(2)$ and $f(\lbrace 5 \rbrace)$ instead of $f(5)$, but yes. You will also need to map the empty set to something too. It is an element of your domain.

Comment: Crucially, you have to remember that $2$ and $5$ are **not** elements of $P(B)$, but $\lbrace 2 \rbrace$ and $\lbrace 5 \rbrace$ are.

Answer (score 3):

$P(B) = \{\emptyset, \{2\}, \{5\},\{2,5\}\}$.  That's four elements (it okay if the elements are themselves sets) and you want to map it to a set of three elements that is onto so that each of the three elements are mapped to.  That's possible because $4$ is a bigger number than $3$.

So we just do it.  $\emptyset$ must get mapped to something.  So let's map it to $e$.  So $f(\emptyset) = e$.  And $\{2\}$ must get mapped to something.  Let's map it to something else just to play it safe.  Let's map it to $f$.  So $f(\{2\}) = f$.

And so on.  Let's make $f(\{5\}) = g$.  Okay, we've made sure everything is mapped to.  So to finish off we must map $\{2,5\}$ to something.  Why not $e$ again.

So for any $C\subset B$ if we define:

$f(C) = \begin{cases}e &\text {if } C = \emptyset\\ f& \text {if }C=\{2\}\\g& \text {if }C =\{5\}\\e&\text {if } C=B \end{cases}$

If an onto function from $P(B)\to A$

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Your first answer is fine.  For 2, note that you are going from the power set of B, not from B itself.  How many elements are in that power set?  Now you just need to make sure that at least one of them goes to each element in A.